# c-basic-offset is not influencing indentation of c/cpp files

Tags: indentation, c

No matter how I set this value I get this message when I try to describe it.

```
Its value is 2
Original value was set-from-style
Local in buffer .... ; *Global value is 3*
```

I don't know what is preventing the global value from applying. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the auto-indent package and it seems to change the default offset. Disabling the plugin helped me verify this.